# Defining Sharded BigQuery Tables on Dataform

Tags: google-bigquery, dataform, google-dataform

Which is the best practice to define/handle BigQuery sharded tables like `table_abc_*` in Dataform?
Is there a way to reference them with `${ref(...)}` and using a sort of `_TABLE_SUFFIX` syntax to select the one we need via variables? I was thinking to create a view on top of it selecting all the fields with the `_table_suffix` statement but this seems to me a workaround more than a way to define those in a proper way.

Comment: when you say sharded, you mean partitioned ?

Comment: Table sharding is the practice of storing data in multiple tables, using a naming prefix such as <PREFIX>_YYYYMMDD.
Every "partition" you have is saved as a different table name. You can query those tables with the `_table_suffix` pseudo field.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_partition_shard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the answer I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/dataform-co/dataform/discussions/1496#discussioncomment-6147106):

table_abc.sqlx

```
config {
  type: "declaration",
  name: "table_abc_*"
}
```

Then you can reference it in your other SQLX files as you wanted:

```
select * from ${ref("table_abc_*")} where _TABLE_SUFFIX = "2018"
```